# How can I hide a URL parameters in Grails App?

Tags: grails

I am sending an id from my view to controller and then again redirecting a new view via that controller, but it is also display the id of the previously created task.How can I hide that in URL and one more thing I only want to redirect from the actions. I don't want to render.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't save params in your url, after you make redirect from your method in such style:

```
redirect(controller: 'yourController', action: 'yourAction')
```

If you want to send your params, you need to do like this:

```
redirect(controller: 'yourController', action: 'yourAction', model: [params])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do GET request from view to your controller->action then id will always show up. You can do a post call for this and later you can do forward so that your url don't change and doesn't show id.

You can also put the id in session, flash.